# How can I access the counter of a ListView in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Listview with binding, and I need the count of this ListView, but I found that in the property ItemSource has the count, but I can't access, Someone cans to help me?

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't posted any relevant code so it's impossible to say what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ListView with an ItemSource binding, you can also bind to the count of the ItemSource.

```
<Label Text="{Binding ItemsList.Count}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't think so 
This is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you set listview's itemssouce, like:

```
collectionlist.itemssource=itemsList;
```

The count of the itemslist is the count of collectionlist.itemssource.

```
   var num=itemsList.Count
```